# Converting a recursive function that return 2 recursion to Iteration

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

I always have problem trying to convert a recursive algorithm which i created that returns 2 recursive call until the base case is met.

It's easy to like track back what each recursive call do but converting them to iteration is a little confusing.

For example this recursive function

```
BEGIN SEQ(n)
   if (n == 1)
     return 3;
   
  else if (n == 2)
     return 2;

  else 
     return SEQ(n - 2) + SEQ(n - 1)
```

This is rather straight forward when i try to rubber duck my way through the recursive which produces the follow process

> SEQ(6) = SEQ(4) + SEQ(5)
>
> SEQ(5) = SEQ(3) + SEQ(4)
>
> SEQ(4) = SEQ(2) + SEQ(3)
>
> SEQ(3) = SEQ(1) + SEQ(2)
>
> SEQ(2) = 2
>
> …
>
> SEQ(3) = 3 + 2 = 5
>
> SEQ(4) = 2 + 5 = 7
>
> SEQ(5) = 5 + 7 = 12
>
> SEQ(6) = 7 + 12 = 19

However, i can't seems to figure out an iteration way that return exactly how the recursive does

Comment: The algorithm does not quite match the example. Did you mean `return SEQ(n-2) + SEQ(n-1)` in the last line?

Comment: Sorry, typo error.

Comment: Apart from the starting values this is built in the same way as the fibonacci sequence. Any iterative program you find for that is easy to modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **iteration** method in C# could look like this:

```
public static int SEQ(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    if (n == 2)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    var first = 3;
    var second = 2;

    for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        second += first;
        first = second - first;
    }


    return second;
}
```